# Set status text with abort function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, http-status-codes

- Laravel Version: 5.5.14
- PHP Version: 7.1.10

#### Description:

When I try to `POST` with `X-Requested-With='XMLHttpRequest'` without `CSRF-TOKEN` I receive `null` message in response.
I add this code to `App\Exceptions\Handler`:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        abort(419, 'Token Mismatch OR page has expired due to inactivity.');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Now I have `Token Mismatch OR page has expired due to inactivity.` message in response, but status text is: `unknown status`.

How can I set status text?

Answer (score 2):

Return a [`\Illuminate\Http\Response`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Response.html) and manually set the status code:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

// snip

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        return (new Response)->setStatusCode(419, "Token Mismatch OR page has expired due to inactivity.");
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: It's correct status text, but response can not `throw new HttpException`.I'm looking for a way that  do it with a `HttpException`.

Answer (score 0):

The Status Code is part of the HTTP Protocol. **419 is not an official status Code** see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes therefor it is unknown.

So `unknown status` is right.

But if you really looking for the file where this is defined, go to:
`/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php`

#### Note:

If you change this file, than you have to do this after every update again.

Comment: Yes, I had found `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php`. but I wanna put my custom status text dynamically

Comment: Than write you own abort function, or hack some of the Core files... no other way